# Show that ($\gcd(a,b)=c$ and $a+b=d$) and ($c|d$) are equivalent

Tags: number-theory

I haven't been able to figure out this question for a while though I'm sure it's pretty straightforward. (It's intuitive to me and difficult to write into a proof).
Show that these statements are equivalent

I) $\gcd(a,b)=c$ and $a+b=d$

II) $c|d$

Comment: The statements are not equivalent.  $5$ divides $2+3$ but $5$ is not gcd$(2,3)$.

Comment: Gcd(2,3)=1... 2+3=5... 1 divides 5.

Comment: Right, so that shows an example wherin $I \implies II$.  But you asked to show that the two are equivalent.  the implication $II \implies I$ is false, see my posted solution below.

Comment: $d$ can never equal $c$.  Assuming both $a$ and $b$ are greater than $0$, then $d$ is greater than either of them, hence can't be a divisor.  But, generally, the divisors of $a+b$ include the common divisors of $a$ and $b$ but it will have lot's of others as well.  Think of the divisors of $12=11+1$.

Answer (score 4):

If all you meant was "show that $I \implies II$" that is straightforward:

Let $c=\gcd(a,b)$.  Write $a=cA$,$b=cB$.  Then $$d=a+b=cA+cB=c(A+B)$$ so $c$ divides $d$.

But the other implication is not even remotely true.  After all $1$ always divides $d$ yet $1$ isn't always the gcd of two specified numbers.  Similarly, $d$ always divides $d$ but $d$ is larger than either $a$ or $b$, hence is not a divisor of either.